# Databinding RichTextBox.Text to a String

Tags: c#, winforms, string, data-binding, richtextbox

Trying to bind a String to a RichTextBox.Text property so that when the String value changes, that change is reflected in the RichTextBox.  So far I'm unsuccessful.

```
string test = "Test";
rtxt_chatLog.DataBindings.Add("Text",test,null);
test = "a";
```

This shows "Test" in the rtxt_chatLog, but not the "a".

Even tried adding rtxt_chatLog.Refresh(); but that does not make any difference.

Update 1:
This does not work either:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

Test t = new Test();
t.Property = "test";
rtxt_chatLog.DataBindings.Add("Text", t, "Property");
t.Property = "a";
```

Am I not understanding data binding correctly?

Comment: what's the purpose of you binding a HardCoded String.. don't you want to go the opposite direction in regards to binding.. what are you truly trying to achieve?? are you wanting some dynamic data from what someone types in like an editbox to bind to the ChatLog or are you really trying to append data to a ChatLog..?

Comment: You bind by value, not by reference. That means that only the current value of `test` ("Test") is passed and no changes to the variable `test` will affect the text box.

Comment: What trying to achieve? Well, I want to keep a log of messages in a string in one window (behind the scenes) and then, at user's request, pop up another window that will list the contents of the string from the parent form in real time.  I want the window to update, as the string in the parent form is updated.  The code snippet is my way of testing the binding.

Comment: Justin, so how would I bind by reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String` class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so there are no *events* for the binding source to tell the RichTextBox that something changed.

Try updating your class with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented:

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string _PropertyText = string.Empty;

  public string PropertyText {
    get { return _PropertyText; }
    set {
      _PropertyText = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("PropertyText");
    }
  }

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
```

}

Also, it looks like `DataBinding` doesn't like the name "Property" for a property name.  Try changing it to something else other than "Property".

```
rtxt_chatLog.DataBindings.Add("Text", t, "PropertyText");
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, I did see something about that interface but was hoping it wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a property for the string variable and handle the string via property always? Its simpler to do under the setter : `rtxt_chatLog.Text = test;`

EDIT: from OP: `Well, I want to keep a log of messages in a string in one window (behind the scenes) and then, at user's request, pop up another window that will list the contents of the string from the parent form in real time`

If you want to list the contents of a string only at user's request, you need nothing of all these. Just need to handle the user's request and do `rtxt_chatLog.Text = test` under that event (probably some eventhandler). But if you need your richtextbox to be populated with every new value for your string you can do something simple:

```
public string Test
{
    set
    { 
        test = value; 
        rtxt_chatLog.Text = test;
    }
    get { return test; }
}
```

The key here is to use only the property through out to set values to variable `test`. For instance, in your code dont do

```
test = "sdf";
```

Do

```
Test = "sdf";
```

Simple.

Comment: I'm confused by what you wrote and unable to follow it.  Which property goes with which string, etc.  But if you look at my first comment to my question, you'll see what I need this for and the code sample you showed does not seem like it would do the trick.

Comment: Not quite, unless we are thinking very differently to begin with. rtxt_chatLog is part of my main form and has it's own separate function, but which I used temporarily for binding testing.  On user's request, I want to pop-up a window with it's own RichTextBox which will show the contents of the string I've been appending to throughout the life of the app. So, with the way I'm thinking, the second RichTextBox does not come to existence until the user chooses to view the messages, which are otherwise being accumulated in the background from application start.

Comment: Given that I have to create a separate object that implements the INotifyChangeProperty I saw that there are actually at lest 2 other approaches to solving my problem.  I can have the pop-up window expose it's RichTextBox and have it be registered in my main form so that it will be populated by code in the main form. Or, I can create my own event which would allow me to create more flexible event handlers in the subscribers as opposed to using the predefined PropertyChangeEventHandler.

Comment: @user983110 //On user's request, I want to pop-up a window with it's own RichTextBox which will show the contents of the string I've been appending to throughout the life of the app. So, with the way I'm thinking, the second RichTextBox does not come to existence until the user chooses to view the messages, // In that scenario why do you want a dynamic update to your rich text box? you need  it only when user attempts to open the popup. So at that instant, why dont you jst load the richttextbox with the current string? We do not get each other well it seems :)

Comment: :) Because I want the requested window to update itself with new messages as they come in while it's open.  I don't want the pop-up window to have static data. If a user wants to see the messages while doing other stuff he/she can, if it's of no interest to the user, then just close or never open that pop-up window.

Comment: @user983110 //to update itself with new messages as they come in while it's open. If a user wants to see the messages while doing other stuff he/she can, if it's of no interest to the user, then just close or never open that pop-up window. // on a nice note let me say, hhhhhhhh, then why dont u just straight away make this point!! :x :D. In that scenario you can go for either approaches in the two answers, mine being simpler, but a bit strange considering you have to access the string via its property.

Comment: For now I have an object that holds a collection of RichTextBoxes and that object is passed into the pop-up window constructor, which then adds its RichTextBox to the collection. Initially this is enough, in the future I might go back to using events.