# Adding a simple databinding to a RichTextBox

Tags: winforms, data-binding, richtextbox

I am interested in binding an object to a RichTextBox so I can append to the object to update the RichTextBox. What class is recommended to be used for the binding? Also, how will `myRichTextBox.DataBindings.Add()` be used with the recommended class?

I have attempted using string as a data binding, but have failed since it seems that strings cannot be used without using a custom class ([C# WinForms databinding RichTextBox.Text to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931982/c-sharp-winforms-databinding-richtextbox-text-to-a-string)).

I have also attempted to use a list of strings through 'myRichTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myListOfStrings, null), but to no avail. I am certain I do not have a clear understanding of the DataMember argument which may be prohibiting me from taking that path.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! An example demonstrating your problem, or what you have done so far, will dramatically increase the chance for a helpful answer.

Comment: The question has been edited to include what I have done so far. Thanks!

Comment: `myRichTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myListOfStrings, null);` should have worked, assuming myListOfStrings is a List<string> collection.  Does myListOfStrings contain elements?  Show the code that isn't working.